# Baixar arquivos pelo link(url) Android

Tags: android, download, apk

Tem como eu baixar um arquivo `.apk` do meu servidor e abri-lo assim que ele terminar de ser baixado?

Sei que não tenho nenhum código mostrando o que já fiz ou tentei, mas é porque sinceramente estou perdido e não sei por onde começar. Tenho um `webservice` em `php` no qual consigo trazer alguns dados do banco por `json` usando o `HttpUrlConnection` se tiver algum exemplo de como fazer isso para baixar um arquivo `.apk` eu agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, será necessária as seguintes permissões em seu **AndroidManifest**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Para que haja acesso a Internet, e para que você que você possa salvar (neste caso na pasta Download).

Para realizar o download, vamos utilizar a classe [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) .

Solicitamos o download, e quando pronto, a resposta vem através de um [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).
Segue um exemplo:

```
//BroadcastReceiver que será invocado ao terminar o download
final BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(intent.getAction() )){
            openFile();
        }
    }
};

DownloadManager downloadManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
  // registramos nosso BroadcastReceiver
  registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(onComplete);
    super.onDestroy();
}
/*
*Abre o arquivo que realizamos o download
*/
private void openFile(){
    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File file = new File(path, "MovieHD.apk");

    Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivity(install);

}

public void iniciarDownload(){
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://dndapps.info/app/MovieHD.apk");

    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
            .mkdirs();

    downloadManager.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
                    .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                    .setTitle("Downlodad")
                    .setDescription("Realizando o download.")
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                            "MovieHD.apk"));
}
```

[Fonte](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Internet/Download/src/com/commonsware/android/download/DownloadDemo.java).

Comment: Eu faço em uma Activity comum mesmo?