# Como atualizar um app proprietário?

Tags: java, android, atualização

Eu tenho um app que deve ser usado só por um número x de funcionários, por isso não está na playstore, mas queria saber como eu posso disponibilizar atualizações e instala-las.

Comment: Eu achei essa pergunta [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130379/baixar-arquivos-pelo-linkurl-android) e era justamente o que preciso.
Mas obrigado pela sua ajuda.
A rotina baixa um arquivo da internet e quando finalizar pede ao android para abrir em uma activity.

Answer (score 2):

Se você gostaria de verificar se você tem app atualizações (sem interagir com o Google Play), você obviamente teria que colocar o app em um servidor (fornecendo sua versão atual) e deixar a verificação do servidor se houver uma versão mais recente disponível. Se for esse o caso, deixe o servidor responder com um changelog e um URL para a versão mais recente.

Existem bibliotecas para fazer isso:

- [Android Auto Update](https://github.com/feicien/android-auto-update): biblioteca em chinês, mas deve fazer o
  truque, longe da biblioteca mas isso pode
  ser apenas porque o Google Play não está disponível na China.
- [AppUpdateChecker](https://github.com/mitmel/AppUpdateChecker) uma forma simples para manter seu
  aplicativo atualizado. Tudo que requer a criação de uma URL que
  aponta para um documento JSON que descreve as mudanças da sua
  aplicação.
- [Auto Updater](https://github.com/NDMAC/android-auto-updater-client) Este projecto permite atualizar
  automaticamente um aplicativo APK execução usando um servidor de
  atualização privado (ver [apk-updater](https://github.com/NDMAC/apk-updater)) em vez de atualizar pelo Google Play. Também vem com um script de servidor.
- [SmartUpdates](https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidSmartUpdates): biblioteca mais velha, mas instruções em Inglês e também fornece um script de servidor.